# What's the difference of runtime between Windows and Linux?

Tags: cross-platform

Recently I tried Qt to make my code cross platform. I compiled the same code under Qt for Windows and Qt for Linux. However, it appears that my program runs normally under Windows but crashes in Linux(randomly). It's hard for me to figure out why it crashes on Linux. Perhaps knowing the difference between Windows and Linux is a good start? Or maybe Windows gets some error-prevention mechanism?

**Update:**
After some work I find that it is the result of `ceil()` function crashes the program.

```
void setPedestriansByRealCo(int &_x,int &_y,myVector &v)
{
    int _row = 0,_colm = 0;
    boost::tuples::tie(_row,_colm) = mathOp::countRowAndColumn(_x,_y);
    setPedestriansByRowColumn(_row,_colm,v);
}

boost::tuples::tuple<int,int> countRowAndColumn(int realX,int realY)
{
    return boost::tuples::make_tuple(
                ceil((float)realY / gridWidth),
                ceil((float)realX / gridWidth)
                );
}
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i < (int)_srcCurrentPointSet.size(); ++i) {
    int _areaRow,_areaColm;
    boost::tuples::tie(_areaRow,_areaColm) = judgePointArea(
                       _srcCurrentPointSet[i],
                       boost::tuples::make_tuple(32,24)); //use the result of countROwAndColumn
    areaPointsCurr[_areaRow * singleAreaColm + _areaColm].push_back(_srcCurrentPointSet[i]);   //<---SIGSEGV
}
```

If input of `countRowAndColumn` was (181,715), then the output in `_srcCurrentPointSet` will be <18,72>, which will cause SIGSEGV in the for loop in Linux(The field is 128*72).

Comment: What exactly cause crash... SIGSEGV?

Comment: I doubt that's likely to be a useful way to debug it. I would just debug the Linux crash directly. Try running it under `valgrind`. Try getting a core dump and analyzing it.

Comment: @janisz     Yes, it is. Qt points to this code:                                         void 
construct(pointer __p, const _Tp& __val) 
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(__val); }        How do I locate the code that causes problem?

Comment: Debug your code in QtCreator, it has nice UI for GDB.

Comment: @janisz Finally figure it out. QtCreator with GDB is a nice tool. I have something that unfamiliar with. Under Windows there also exists SIGSEGV but the program can "endure" it, however, in Linux the program crashes. Does that mean Linux is much more strict?

Comment: @user957121 good question. Can you post some code. It will be easier to construct an answer because IMO problem lies in your code not in different OS behavior.

Comment: @janisz Could you please tell me that where can I post my code since copying my code into the comment box makes the code look like "Monster":)

Comment: Whats the value of gridWidth when it crashes? Maybe it's zero or not initialized. _srcCurrentPointSet[i] could also be out of bounds.

Comment: @user957121 make a break point before broken line and check all variables and container sizes.

Comment: @atamanroman gridWidth is a enum variable, equal to 10. I've checked the _srcCurrentPointSet[i] array, no out of bounds was found.

Comment: @janisz I changed ceil() into floor(), which solved my problem.